# How to depend on a subproject’s sourceset?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I would like to use my test classes from one subproject in the other one instead of doubling code.

I have two subprojects like so

```
.
├── project
├── subproject1
│   ├── main
│   │   └──...
│.  ├── intTest
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
├── subproject2
│   ├── main
│   │   └──...
│.  ├── intTest
│   │   └──...
│   └── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

`subproject2` depends on `subproject1`.

`subproject2` `build.gradle`..

```
sourceSets {
    intTest {
        scala {
            srcDirs("intTest/scala")
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs("intTest/resources")
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation project(":subproject1")
...
}
```

`subproject2` has access to `subproject1` classes but only for `main` sourceSet, it doesn't see `intTest` ( and neither do `main` in subproject1 but thats normal?).

How can I make it so `subproject2` depends on subproject1 `intTest` sourceSet

Comment: Looks like [IDEA-165392](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165392/Incorrect-gradle-multiproject-dependencies-with-custom-sourceSets) **Incorrect gradle multiproject dependencies with custom sourceSets** issue. Try as a workaround add `implementation project(': subproject1').sourceSets. intTest.output`

Comment: Tried, there is no property sourceSets:
"> Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for project ':subproject1' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: Are the classes in `intTest` actual tests that are annotated with test annotations like `@Test` from JUnit Jupiter? Or are they utility classes or POJOs that aid in writing tests?

Comment: I'm using scala's scalatests playframework implementation. I intend to import i.e BaseTest classes with boilerplate code that is reused in subproject.